# Java JDateChooser setCaretposition(0) does not work

Tags: java, jdatechooser

When I make the `jDateChooser.requestFocusInWindow()`  the cursor goes to the end of the date field, I want the cursor to be set at the beginning, the function `setCaretPosition(0)` does not work in this case. How can I set the cursor at the beginning of the field?

thanks,

jm

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of `JDateChooser` , you may specify the `IDateEditor` to use.

In your case `JTextFieldDateEditor` (which is probably the default one) looks good.

Once you have your editor, just call `setCaretPosition(0)` on it .

Example :

```
JTextFieldDateEditor editor = new JTextFieldDateEditor();

JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser(editor);
dateChooser.setDate(new Date());

editor.setCaretPosition(0);
```

Comment: You're welcome. Consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem :)